# What is Swipe Options in Settings?

Tags: ios, settings, mobile-mail

What are swipe options and what are their functions?

Answer (score 1):

In Mail on iOS, you can swipe messages left or right to perform quick actions on that message, such as archiving or marking as read. The action performed when swiping in a certain direction is configured in Settings → Mail (Contacts & Calendars) → Swipe Options.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly delete an email, swipe left or right and hold. This would allow all three swipe functions (schedule, archive and delete) to be simultaneously available.